# Can lightsabers be periwinkle?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I'm trying to find some canonical support for a jedi, dark jedi or Sith who wield a periwinkle lightsaber. Periwinkle is a different color than Ochre, incidentally. Periwinkle= sRGBB-204, 204, 255. Ochre= sRGBB-204, 119, 34. For anyone with enough time on their hands to identify (non) duplicate questions on a science fiction and fantasy website, I'd think that research would have been done. At any rate, Comic-Book-Guys' concerns aside, does anyone know if there is evidence for such a thing?

[image]

Comment: So somewhere between Mace Windu and Obi-Wan Kenobi?

Comment: Yeah more or less. I just hope there is something to support it canonically. Can't find anything in the films, and not sure if Zahn's books or the animated series are considered canon. It's really important to me.

Comment: You are asking two questions, I think - one is much easier than the other.  The first is if a lightsaber can be a color (almost certainly), the other is if anyone ever used a specific color (harder, and will almost certainly take a lot of video watching, I don't remember anyone in the novels describing a saber as such).

Comment: Yes, the two colors are different, but the answers and reasons are pretty much the same: the usage of synthetic crystals makes *any* color possible. As for whether or not there is evidence of periwinkle in specific, you may note the list of colors in the other answer - periwinkle is not specifically listed as the color of any existing lightsaber. There are, however, a few that come close being similar shades of purple/blue.

Comment: Arguing that the colour is different doesn't make it a different question.  Otherwise one could go through every 0-255 RGB combination and claim over 16,000,000 unique questions.

Comment: So you think "Is your car blue?" is the same question as "Is your car red?"? It's clearly not. And so what if there are 160,000 questions about color? Are the potential number of questions a template question might generate a grounds for it being dismissed?

Comment: Sorry but that's not valid.  The *real* question is "what colours can a car be?", not "can a car be red?", "can a car be blue?", "can a car be green?", "can a car be orange?", "can a car be purple?", etc etc etc.

Comment: You didn't ask "is your car blue/red" or even "is obi-wan's lightsaber blue/red" - you asked 1) *Can lightsabers be periwinkle?* As stated in the other Q/A, synthetic crystals make any color possible. 2) *Does anyone have a periwinkle lightsaber?* As stated in the other Q/A, there are currently no lightsabers described as periwinkle. Both of your questions have already been answered.

Comment: Yet you insist on being a Comic Book Guy and belaboring the point.

Answer (score 8):

There's a very good list of canonically seen lightsaber colours [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal). None of the blades  mentioned are "periwinkle" but given the wide spectrum available, there doesn't seem to be a reason why such a thing would be *impossible*.

As the same articles notes;

> **Lightsaber crystals of different hues could also be used in the same
>   lightsaber to make a new blade color**; for example, Galen Marek used
>   Rahm Kota's green crystal along with his father's blue crystal to
>   create an aqua blade.

Presumably then you could take the purple crystal from Mace Windu's saber and combine it with the crystal from Ki-Lu's Saberstaff to make a periwinkle blade

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course, if you did that, you'd also have to find some pink & white robes to go with it.